# What would the likely color of an exoplanet's plants be depending on the combination of atmosphere & parent star?

Tags: biology, planets, atmosphere, flora, stars

This could be construed as a too broad question, but some examples is all I'm asking for really. An answer based on **any combination** of atmosphere and star would constitute a good answer. 
*(Or better yet, some simple way to determine what wavelength likely would be reflected by a plant in any given conditions.)*

Different stars radiate different spectrums of light, and different atmospheres absorb- and scatter different amounts of different wavelengths of light.

One could assume plants would evolve to absorb the wavelengths most readily available for photosynthesis, with some wavelengths being more useful options than others, of course.

What would be the color of alien plants under some example conditions, then?

Edit: From the commments it would seem plant color is a lot more arbitrary than I gave it credit for. So I consider this pretty much answered. :)

Comment: You can choose any color you like because one can find a chemical that fits. I wouldn't go too far away from the visible spectrum though. Nobody knows for sure which specific molecules would evolve on some random planet next to some random star, so this is left to your imagination. If you want to ask about a specific molecule/complex, you should go ahead and do that. But please be aware of one thing: Color vision/perception depends on your environment (and so on).  It is not reasonable to assume an alien that sees plants as "blue" but only a human traveler that perceives them as blue

Comment: *"One could assume plants would evolve to absorb the wavelengths most readily available for photosynthesis":* this is more tricky than it sounds. For example, here on Earth the maximum power is in the green part of the spectrum, but most plants _reflect_ green; and there are red, brown and blue algae. Green plants are green simply because they are descended from green algae; it just happened so, but it could have been equally possible to have plants descended from red algae, or from blue-green algae, or from brown algae.

Comment: I also think the color of plants would be a fairly random thing in alternative evolution, but most likely prevalent. Chlorophyll is an evolved machine that does a job, it reflects green by accident of the particular arrangement of atoms in the machine. Some combo of efficiency and "right place, right time" luck made it the most prevalent on Earth; elsewhere something else might win. Evolution does not *require* optimality; it tends toward it as a competitive advantage, but often, being first and becoming ubiquitous can "starve out" the marginally better if it appears; sometimes literally.